# grub2 installation fails for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, mount, 16.04

I have been trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 on my Lenovo Ideapad500-15isk alongside windows 7 using a usb live disc.

I have kept 8200MB of swap space

and 20482MB of mount point /

and around 390 GB of space with mount point /home.

I downloaded the 64 bit ISO file from http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ and used rufus as well as the Startup disc creator in Ubuntu to create the live disc.

But the Ubuntu Installation fails to load grub 2 every time. What could have possibly gone wrong?

Also since I'm already using a 64bit windowsi doubt that is the problem.

Comment: Can you please provide more information? Maybe like the error it gives you?

Comment: @Inforcer25 it says  "The 'grubb-efi-amd64-signedd' package failed to install into /target/ .Without the GRUB boot loader, the installed system will not boot"

Comment: Is your Windows 7 installed with the [hidden partition](http://ccm.net/faq/3917-windows-7-the-hidden-partition)? My install of Grub2 in Ubuntu 14.04 broke every time until I [removed it](https://www.terabyteunlimited.com/kb/article.php?id=409).

Comment: @Melebius I think i do habe that partition. Doesnt removing it creaate any problems with windows for instance loading last successful boot?

Comment: It should work correctly if you follow the instructions carefully. However, one should do a Clonezilla backup first.

Comment: @Melebius the partiotion happens to be empty do i still need to carry on?

Comment: Have you mounted it to Windows and found it empty? (https://www.terabyteunlimited.com/kb/article.php?id=409, step 2) Other methods may be not reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Recent Windows versions (most likely starting with Windows 7) create a hidden boot partition by default and Linux installers seem not to be able to handle it correctly.

**Is this your case?**

In Windows, run `diskmgmt.msc`. Your primary disk starts with a **System Reserved partition** of size 100–200 MB. Click on the disk’s grey field in the left and open Properties. On the Volumes page, the Partition style is **Master Boot Record (MBR)**.

**Solution**

1. Get a spare drive and backup your current drive setup with [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) or similar software. **It can save your system if you do a mistake in the following procedure!**
2. Make the partition visible to Windows, move its data to C: and update settings of the boot manager. Use this detailed guide: https://www.terabyteunlimited.com/kb/article.php?id=409
3. Once Windows boot fine without their hidden partition, you can install Linux to make a dual-boot setup.

**References**

- https://www.terabyteunlimited.com/kb/article.php?id=409
- http://winsupersite.com/article/windows-7/windows-7-release-candidate-review-part-3-other-changes--in-the-release-candidate
- http://woshub.com/removable-usb-flash-drive-as-local-disk-in-windows-7/

Comment: I am sorry but the suggestion didn't help. I installed Ubuntu 15.10 instead. I think this has to be some bug with ubuntu 16.04. Also can you suggest some webpage to undo the suggested procedure?

Comment: @MayankModi Just doing the steps in reverse? However, I wouldn’t bother with it if everything works.